# Creating free remote database and connecting to shinyapp (locally or hosted in AWS/shinyapps.io)

Tags: mysql, r, database, shiny, shinyapps

Could anyone please guide me on the below problem:

I have this shinyapp that is being used by multiple users. Let's say all users can add data points (in a tabular structure e.g. name, DOB, salary, etc.) from the shinyapp to the database. Again when the users log in to the app, they will be able to see the same data.

Where I can create a free database and be able to remote connect with the shiny apps. I should be able to access the DB from the local shinyapp environment as well as from the hosted app on the server (AWS/shinyapps.io). App users should be able to read/write to the DB.

I am aware of this post on [persistent storage](https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/) but not totally sure how can I create a free DB and access it through the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no *free* (in the sense of no cost) service that can provide database storage: **someone has to pay for the server that runs that database** ;)

That being said, you can definitely connect your `{shiny}` application to any open source database system: PostGres, MongoDB...
If you can afford to deploy your app on your own server, you can definitely launch a DB service on that exact service too.

Otherwise, Google Cloud or AWS will give you access to services like this.

I suppose that if you want something free, your data I/O is not large, so one solution can also be to use a Google Sheet as a backend: it can take longer to write there, but you'll get this for free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The data I/O is not large; and I think it make sense to use googlesheet or dropbox

Comment: Great, in that case I suggest using `{googlesheets4}` https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4 :). Btw, feel free to accept this answer if it answers your original question.